# Rendering react components serverside. Compile css for react-view

Tags: reactjs, sass, koa

I want to share my components globally. Instead of going with the common isomorphic route I decided to use this guy https://github.com/koajs/react-view.

I can generate user data server side and pass into the koa `render` method. From there I can import existing components.

I am doing it this way because I have a web app, and a subdomain route that generates a website for my users. I want to share components between the web app and the generated website. So this seems perfect.

However I am using webpack. Webpack allows me to import scss to my component. The `react-view` lib does not.

My question is how can I compile the imported scss when I am importing the components to the index file rendered by koa?

Comment: See how it's done in this project: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

Comment: Nice. Is it a webpack thing. Or a node.js thing?

Comment: It's https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader

Comment: Since you decorate the component `withStyles` would it interfere with redux `connect`? Or do you think I could decorate the `connect` method. Thanks by the way.